# in python2.7 how to align the text with the button

Tags: python, label, tk-toolkit

in python 2.7 I'm trying to align the text frankie anne so its next to the name button and 27 so its next to the age button can only get them in center so far. tried left and bottom already didn't work. any help would be helpful.

```
from Tkinter import *

root = Tk()

toolbar = Frame(root)

b = Button(toolbar, text="Home", width=9)
b.pack(side=LEFT, padx=2, pady=2)

b = Button(toolbar, text="About-us", width=9)
b.pack(side=LEFT, padx=2, pady=2)

b = Button(toolbar, text="Contact-us", width=9)
b.pack(side=LEFT, padx=2, pady=2)

b = Button(toolbar, text="Travelling", width=9)
b.pack(side=LEFT, padx=2, pady=2)



toolbar.pack(side=TOP, fill=X)

o = Label(root,text="Frank Anne",font =("Italic",18,"bold"))
o.pack()
toolbar1 = Frame(root)
b = Button(toolbar1, text="Name",width=9)
b.pack(side=LEFT, padx=2, pady=2)

o = Label(root,text="27",font =("Italic",10,"bold"))
o.pack()

o = Label(root,text="Frankie anne",font =("Italic",10,"bold"))
o.pack(side=TOP, padx=0, pady=0)


toolbar1.pack(side=BOTTOM, fill=X)


toolbar2 = Frame(root)
b = Button(toolbar2, text="Age",width=9)
b.pack(side=LEFT, padx=2, pady=2)
b.pack(side=BOTTOM, padx=2, pady=2)



toolbar2.pack(side=BOTTOM, fill=X)

mainloop()
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add `side=LEFT` to your objects and intersparce `\n` in with your texts to make new lines. I'm a little confused on why you have a toolbar2 with an age button when the age text is part of toolbar 1. I would probably group those together too depending on what you want.